# Character-location identity to create a new variable

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

lets first take some random data

```
A <- c(1:5)
score_one <- c(123.5, 223.1, 242.2, 351.8, 123.1)
score_two <- c(324.2, 568.2, 124.9, 323.1, 213.4)
score_three <- c(553.1, 412.3, 435.7, 523.1, 365.4)
score_four <- c(123.2, 225.1, 243.6, 741.1, 951.2)


df1 <- data.frame(A, score_one, score_two, score_three, score_four)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df2 <- df1 %>% 
  group_by(A) %>% 
  mutate_each(funs(substr(.,1,1))) %>%                
  ungroup %>%
  gather(variable, type, -c(A)) %>%                     
  select(-variable) %>%
  mutate(type = paste0("type_",type),
         value = 1) %>%
  group_by(A,type) %>%                                     
  summarise(value = sum(value)) %>% 
  ungroup %>%
  spread(type, value, fill=0) %>%                       
  inner_join(df1, by=c("A")) %>%                            
  select(A, starts_with("score_"), starts_with("type_"))
```

This introduces a summary variable for each `score_` 
and counts the frequency of each unique *first-digit number*

Hence we see in row one, type_1 == 2. Because in the corresponding `score_` columns we have 2 occurrences where the number 1 is the first number

**Problem Statement**
now we want introduce a variable that calls upon the `type_n` columns.

- It checks if the value > 0.
- when this is the case, we want to inspect the corresponding `score_` column/s
- here we analyse if the digit *after the decimal* place is >= than the value 2
- now if one or all of the corresponding rows' value after the decimal place are >= 2, **we want to assign a value of 1**
- if all of the corresponding rows' value after the decimal place are < 2, **we want to assign a value of 0**
- and consequnetly, if `type_n == 0`, **we want to assign a 0**
- say we name this variable `$type_n_G2`

such that the desired output should look like[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/St4pX.jpg)

[image]

Taking for example, `type_1_G2`

- we have `type_1 == 2`
- we have the corresponding identities at `score_one` and `score_four`
- both values after the decimal place are >= 2, so we assign `type_1_G2==1`

Comment: I don't understand what's the desired output. There is too much code and wording here that I can't see what are you actually trying to achieve.

Comment: In your example I don't understand why do you choose the score_one and score_four? Since you are evaluating type_1 shouldn't just be score_one?

Comment: we want to inspect both `score_one` and `score_four` since both of these begin with `== 1`

Comment: The values in the provided data set don't match your image. `score_four` in row 1 is 123.1 and not 123.2, score_one at second row is 223.7 and not 223.1. and etc

Comment: Still gives me wrong values in some rows

Comment: I have updated the data frame

Comment: According to your sample the logic is only `if(type_X > 0) type_X_G2 = 1 else type_X_G2=0` as there's no row where the scores decimal will be under any type value.... *sigh*

Comment: Downvoting, make a correct input example and craft an expected output with all edge cases so the answers could be verified against it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no need for the complicated construction of `df2` in my opinion. A reshaped `df1` into long format is a better starting point to get to the desired end result in fewer steps.

An approach using the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
# melting the original dataframe 'df1' to a long format datatable
dt <- melt(setDT(df1), "A")

# creating two type variables & a logical vector indicating whether
# the decimal for a specific type is equal or above .2
dt[, `:=` (type1=paste0("type_",substr(value,1,1)),
           type2=paste0("type_",substr(value,1,1),"_g2"))
   ][, g2 := +(+(value - floor(value) >= 0.2)==1), .(A,type1)]

# creating separate wide datatables for the variable & two type columns
dt1 <- dcast(dt, A ~ variable)
dt2 <- dcast(dt, A ~ type1)
dt3 <- dcast(dt, A ~ type2, fun=sum, value.var="g2")[, lapply(.SD, function(x) +(x>=1)), A]

# two options for merging the wide datatables together into one
dtres <- dt1[dt2[dt3, on = "A"], on = "A"]
dtres <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = TRUE, by = "A"), list(dt1, dt2, dt3))

# or in one go without creating intermediate datatables
dtres <- dcast(dt, A ~ variable)[dcast(dt, A ~ type1)[dcast(dt, A ~ type2, fun=sum, value.var = "g2")[, lapply(.SD, function(x) +(x>=1)) , A], on = "A"], on = "A"]
```

this results in:

```
> dtres
   A score_one score_two score_three score_four type_1 type_2 type_3 type_4 type_5 type_7 type_9 type_1_g2 type_2_g2 type_3_g2 type_4_g2 type_5_g2 type_7_g2 type_9_g2
1: 1     123.5     324.2       553.1      123.2      2      0      1      0      1      0      0         1         0         0         0         0         0         0
2: 2     223.1     568.2       412.3      225.1      0      2      0      1      1      0      0         0         0         0         1         1         0         0
3: 3     242.2     124.9       435.7      243.6      1      2      0      1      0      0      0         1         1         0         1         0         0         0
4: 4     351.8     323.1       523.1      741.1      0      0      2      0      1      1      0         0         0         1         0         0         0         0
5: 5     123.1     213.4       365.4      951.2      1      1      1      0      0      0      1         0         1         1         0         0         0         1
```

---

This approach can be translated into a `dplyr`/`tidyr` implementation as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- df1 %>% gather(variable, value,-A) %>%
  mutate(type1 = paste0("type_",substr(value,1,1)),
         type2 = paste0("type_",substr(value,1,1),"_g2")) %>%
  group_by(A,type1) %>%
  mutate(g2 = +(+(value - floor(value) >= 0.2)==1),
         type1n = n()) %>%
  ungroup()

d1 <- df %>% select(1:3) %>% spread(variable, value)
d2 <- df %>% group_by(A, type1) %>% tally() %>% spread(type1, n, fill=0)
d3 <- df %>% group_by(A, type2) %>% summarise(g = any(g2==1)) %>% spread(type2, g, fill=0)

dfres <- left_join(d1, d2, by = "A") %>% left_join(., d3, by = "A")
```

which gives the same result:

```
> dfres
  A score_one score_two score_three score_four type_1 type_2 type_3 type_4 type_5 type_7 type_9 type_1_g2 type_2_g2 type_3_g2 type_4_g2 type_5_g2 type_7_g2 type_9_g2
1 1     123.5     324.2       553.1      123.2      2      0      1      0      1      0      0         1         0         0         0         0         0         0
2 2     223.1     568.2       412.3      225.1      0      2      0      1      1      0      0         0         0         0         1         1         0         0
3 3     242.2     124.9       435.7      243.6      1      2      0      1      0      0      0         1         1         0         1         0         0         0
4 4     351.8     323.1       523.1      741.1      0      0      2      0      1      1      0         0         0         1         0         0         0         0
5 5     123.1     213.4       365.4      951.2      1      1      1      0      0      0      1         0         1         1         0         0         0         1
```

Comment: Great use of efficient coding to not require the df2. The second solution using the `dpylr`/`tidyr`worked great. However I get an error at dt2 and dt3 when using the `data.table`method

Comment: @lukeg It's working for me. Which version of `data.table` are you using?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a vectorized attempt to first `melt` and then `dcast` the data using the `data.table` package. It needs some polish but I don't have time right now

```
library(data.table) # v >= 1.9.6
# melt and order by "A" 
temp <- setorder(melt(df2, id = 1:5), A)

# Create the "type_n_G2" column names
temp$Var <- paste0(temp$variable, "_G2")

# Selecting only the "score_one", "score_two", "score_three" and "score_four"
indx1 <- indx2 <- temp[2:5]

# Finding the first integer within each number
indx2[] <- sub("(^.{1}).*", "\\1", as.matrix(indx2))

# The works horse: simultaneously compare `indx2` against `type_n` and extract decimals
indx3 <- indx1 * (indx2 == as.numeric(sub(".*_", "", temp$variable))) - floor(indx1)

# Compare the result against 0.2, sum the rows and see if any is greater than 0
temp$res<- +(rowSums(indx3 >= 0.2) > 0)

# Convert back to wide format
dcast(temp, A ~ Var, value.var = "res")
#   A type_1_G2 type_2_G2 type_3_G2 type_4_G2 type_5_G2 type_7_G2 type_9_G2
# 1 1         1         0         0         0         0         0         0
# 2 2         0         1         0         1         1         0         0
# 3 3         1         1         0         1         0         0         0
# 4 4         0         0         1         0         0         0         0
# 5 5         0         1         1         0         0         0         1
```

Now you can just `cbind` the result to `df2` (This doesn't match your result exactly cause your provided data doesn't match it too)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed comments to explain the method.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an attempt, transforming your data to a `long` format to keep for each value the `type` variable. This then makes it easier to count how many have decimals `>=2` in the second step.

```
library(tidyr)

#transform df1 to the long format
df <- df1 %>% gather(key, value, -A)

 #calculate the type for each line
 #this can be done by extracting the first digit and pasting 
 # "_type" in front of it
df$type <- as.factor(paste("type",sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$value),""),function(x) x[[1]]),sep="_"))

 #expand the levels to add missing types
levels(df$type) <- c(levels(df$type),setdiff(paste("type",1:9,sep="_"),levels(df$type)))

#create a new column that holds the first decimal
#I assumed there was only one decimal for each number 
#but you can adapt this
df$first_decimal <- as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$value),"[.]"),function(x) x[[2]]))

#group by A and type, if any first_decimal is bigger than 2
#G2 will be set to one for that group
df <- df %>% group_by(A,type) %>% mutate(G2=any(first_decimal>=2)*1)

#create a type_G2 column to hold the final column labels
df$type_G2 <- paste0(df$type,"_G2")

#this cbind creates the final result
cbind(df1,as.data.frame.matrix(table(df[,c("A","type")])),spread(unique(df[,c("A","type_G2","G2")]),key=type_G2,value=G2,drop=FALSE,fill=0)[,-1])
```

Breakdown of the last cbind:

`df1` is the original dataframe

`as.data.frame.matrix(table(df[,c("A","type")]))` is a dataframe that holds the number of each `type`

`spread(unique(df[,c("A","type_G2","G2")]),key=type_G2,value=G2,drop=FALSE,fill=0)[,-1]` holds the `type_G2` info. I unique the subsetted df because there is some redundant information (for example `type_1_G2` is the same for the values 123.5 and 123.1 of the first line).

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: after re reading once more the question, my answer is false (at least it over-complex in the result), leaving it in case you wish to compare the decimal value toward the number of occurrence of each first digit.

---

In case you're willing to compare score decimal to each type_N value in this row here's a way, hopefully there's clever peoples here who will be able to improve this:

```
decimalscores <- (df2[grepl("score_*",colnames(df2))] - floor(df2[grepl("score_*",colnames(df2))]))*10 # Get the decimal, as per the sample only one digit 
typesindex <- as.numeric(sub("type_","",colnames(df2[grepl("type_*",colnames(df2))]))) # get  the type_"n" columns names to reuse later
res <- t(sapply(1:nrow(df2),function(x) { # loop over the dataframe rows
    sapply(typesindex,function(y) { # For each type index  
        colname <- paste0("type_",y)
        cmptype <- unlist(unname(df2[x,colname]))
        # create the result if type_n is above 0 
        ifelse(cmptype > 0,
               any(unlist(unname(decimalscores[x,])) >= cmptype)+0L, # If one score is above the value return 1
               0) # Else return 0
     })
  }))
colnames(res) <- paste0("type_",typesindex,"_G2") # Name the resulting columns by adding _G2 to ouptut
res <- as.data.frame(res) # turn matrix into dataframe
df3 <- cbind(df2,res) # bind them to get expected output
```

I hope the comments are explaining it enough, if something is unclear, tell me.